# Translating 「こんなばかな私をどうして愛してくれるの？」

Tags: grammar, translation

Someone I know PM'd me this and I honestly don't know what it means.

> こんなばかな私をどうして愛してくれるの？

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this is roughly:

> Konna baka na watashi o doushite ai shite kureru no?

And for the individual words I've got

- Konna - this is

  Baka - stupid

  Watashi o - I

  Ai - Love

But from that, I don't know how it transforms into an actual sentence or at least its meaning. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: How did you come up with your translations for the four words/phrases you list, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 3):

> **Q. Can someone translate and explain this to me?
>   
> 「こんなばかな私をどうして愛してくれるの？」**

**A.** First I'll break it down and then give what *may* be an explanation for the sentence.

- こんな - this kind of
- ばかな - idiot, stupid

  - **こんなばかな** - this kind of stupid
- 私 - me

  - **こんなばかな私** - this kind of stupid person (literally "me")
- を - particle that marks the object of the sentence
- どうして - why
- 愛して - gerund form of 愛する (to love)
- くれる - to give; to let one have; to do for one; to be given

  - **愛してくれる** - (give) love (to) me, i.e., love me
- の - particle の used at the end of a sentence when one is seeking for an explanation for something

Thus, the sentence holds the following meaning:

**こんなばかな私をどうして愛してくれるの？

 Why do you love this kind of stupid person?** (referring to themself)

or more loosely translated: **How can you love a person as stupid as me?**

The author of the sentence may be seeking confirmation of the recipient's love, but that's just a conjecture. The author could be seeking a range of different reactions with this. Only the author (and possibly the recipient, and those familiar with the situation) would know this based on the context and their relationship.